# How much does vertical-align:super raise the baseline

Tags: html, css

Hi I wonder if there is a standard ratio that the CSS attribute `vertical-align:super;` raise the baseline.

I need the exact pixel value for some animation that requires me to know the new baseline after text become `vertical-align:super;`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can vary from browser to browser. I would recommend using percentages or pixels, you can then have complete control over the height. For example:

`vertical-align: 10px;`
or
`vertical-align: 10%;`